# svn: sync branch with trunk, but commit only trunk's diffs to branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

Say I have a working directory of a branch which has uncommitted changes. But in the meantime I want to sync to the HEAD of trunk, how would I do that?
In GIT I would just use rebase. In SVN I would have to look at which diffs (after a svn merge) would be produced by me - before the merge - and which diffs originate from trunk. If I identified the latter I can then do a commit and be synced with trunk.

Of course I can do a new checkout and do the merging there, but why should I need to do this for such a common scenario ?

Comment: Branch with uncommited changes, which you (want|don't want) to merge with thunk?

Comment: I want trunk's changes to be merged into the branch - i.e. sync'ed. But at the point before merging from trunk I might have local changes. Then after having done the merge, I only want to commit the changes which came from trunk, but they are indistinguishable from my own changes. Ergo, I'm missing something like GIT's  stash functionality.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch branch to another (maybe empty) branch TEMPBRANCH
2. Commit to TEMPBRANCH
3. Switch back
4. Merge trunk
5. Merge TEMPBRANCH or (probably better) only last revision in TEMPBRANCH
6. Remove TEMPBRANCH

Comment: This is not much better then doing a new checkout in a different directory, sync-commit, and update in the original checkout. Am to conclude that SVN does not have a simple oneliner for this?